# Obtener mínimo de un array con c#

Tags: c#, array

Tengo una pregunta, estoy aprendiendo a utilizar C# (Mi primer lenguaje) y deseo obtener ciertos datos como el promedio, máximo y menor de un array pero al ingresar la condición para que me de el número menor me arroja cero. no se supone que el if evalua cada condición obligatoriamente? Esta clase la estoy llamando desde un main:

```
public void calculoArray()
{
   entradas = new float[nEntradasParseado];

   for (int j = 0; j < entradas.Length; j++)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Digite el valor {0} de temperatura", (j + 1));
      entradas[j] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      total += entradas[j];
      promedio = total / nEntradasParseado;
            
      if (entradas[j] > numeroMayor)
      {
         numeroMayor = entradas[j];
      }

      if (entradas[j] < numeroMenor && entradas[0] != 0)
      {
         numeroMenor = entradas[j];
      }
   }
}

public void Mostrar()
{
   Console.WriteLine("El promedio es {0}" ,promedio);
   Console.WriteLine("el numero mayor es {0}",numeroMayor);
   Console.WriteLine("El numero menor es {0}", numeroMenor);
}
```

Comment: ¿por que estas verificando que el primer numero de entrada sea diferente que 0?

Comment: En donde se declara e inicializa numeroMayor y numeroMenor?

Comment: Usa variables locales a menos que necesites usarlas en otra parte. Sino tendrás que reiniciarlas cada vez que llames la función (cosa que no veo que hagas).

Comment: Hola Jonathan, podrías marcar como aceptada la respuesta que más te haya ayudado, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el promedio, máximo y menor de un arreglo puedes hacer uso de **Linq** de esta forma ahorrarás mucho código:

```
public void calculoArray()
{
   entradas = new float[nEntradasParseado];

   for(int j = 0; j < entradas.Length; j++)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Digite el valor {0} de temperatura", (j + 1));
      entradas[j] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   }

   var numeroMenor = entradas.Min();
   var numeroMayor= entradas.Max();
   var promedio = entradas.Average(); 

   Console.WriteLine("El promedio es {0}", promedio);
   Console.WriteLine("el número mayor es {0}", numeroMayor);
   Console.WriteLine("El número menor es {0}", numeroMenor);
}
```

Lo primero que se hace es un **ciclo for** para llenar el arreglo, posteriormente se llaman a los **operadores Min**, **Max** y **Average** de **Linq**, los cuales obtienen el valor mínimo del arreglo, el valor máximo del arreglo y el promedio del arreglo. Por último se imprimen los resultados obtenidos.

Para hacer uso del **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Gracias!! no tenia ni idea

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no estás inicializando `numeroMayor` y `numeroMenor` por lo que entiendo que (al ser globales, que no deberían como te indican en los comentarios) las tienes inicializadas a 0. Lo que debes es inicializarlas al primer elemento del array (suponiendo que existe claro). Algo así:

```
numeroMayor = entradas[0];
numeroMenor = entradas[0];
```

De esta forma el resto de las comparaciones se realizan en relación con un elemento del vector.
En cualquier caso deberías hacer funciones distintas para las distintas tareas y en cada una de ellas comprobar que el vector es válido (no nulo) y tiene elementos.
En tu caso al hacer todo en el mismo bucle deberás en la primera vuelta quedarte con el primer valor que te introducen.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes que no quieras usar [LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/).

En primer lugar, no parece que reinicies las variables que usas. Dudo que quieras tener un total anterior acumulado, ni un número mayor ni menor a los que existen en el arreglo actualmente.

Restablécelos dentro de la función o usa variables locales e inicialízalas:

```
total = 0;
numeroMayor = float.MinValue;
numeroMenor = float.MaxValue;
```

Puede que te preguntes por qué uso `float.MinValue` y `float.MaxValue`.

La razón es que como `numeroMayor` solo puede aumentar, quieres que contenga el menor número posible.

Supón que lo inicias en 0. Y que tienes un arreglo con los elementos -8, -1 y -4. El número mayor será 0 porque todos son menores que 0. Y 0 ni siquiera forma parte del arreglo. Por eso se inicia en `float.MinValue`.

Con `numeroMenor` pasa algo parecido. ¿Qué pasa si los elementos del arreglo están todos por encima del valor? `numeroMenor` conservará su valor inicial. Entonces lo inicias en `float.MaxValue`.

---

Otra opción es que inicies las 2 variables a comparar con algún elemento del arreglo. Por simplicidad el primero. Entonces recorres el arreglo desde el segundo elemento.

```
numeroMayor = entradas[0];
numeroMenor = entradas[0];

for (int i = 1; i < entradas.Length; i++){
    ...
}
```

La ventaja de esta forma es que el valor inicial es un elemento del arreglo. Por lo tanto no tienes que asegurarte de que los números iniciales no molesten en la comparación.

Puede que esta forma no se adapte a tu código. Así que tendrás adaptarla o adaptarte tú.

Comment: Gracias! veo que me falta mucho estudio aún, no sabia de linq